# How can I know how much memory Eclipse plugins use (separately)

Tags: performance, eclipse, memory, eclipse-plugin, memory-consumption

Is there a way to know how much memory is consumed by each Eclipse plugin separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a heap dump and analyse it with e.g. the [Eclipse Memory Analyser](http://eclipse.org/mat/).

For more information, see [Analyzing Equinox Bundle Dependencies with Memory Analyzer](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/memoryanalyzer/2008/11/28/analyzing-the-equinox-bundle-dependencies-with-memory-analyzer/)

Comment: Even though this is only good for a one-time snapshot analysis and cannot be used at runtime, I think it is the best bet to get an idea of the memory usage of a certain plugin. It is gonna be tedious work, but I do not see any other chance. Make sure you use a representative dataset for your plugin, or your results could be far off.

Answer (score 1):

I would be quite surprised if this were possible, because you would have to have an unambiguous way of determining which plugin "owned" a particular object on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 3.1 has a built-in Memory Monitor (aka Heap Status) Plugin, which is a part of org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.1.0.jar You have to run Eclipse in debug mode for seeing the monitor in right lower corner.

Also check FreeMem plugin:[FreeMem plugin](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-307.html)

In Eclipse you can uninstall-->measure memory-->install-->repeat cycle

That way you can find out about any/all memory utilization of each plugin.
Good luck with this task.  I'd be interested to see the results because I see that some plugins utilize much more memory then others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any generic answer but maybe it is possible to get the memory usage of some plugins: as the framework loads plugins on demand if you can read the heap size before and after the activation of the plugin it might give an idea.

To check which plugins are loaded, the 'ss' command can be used in the OSGi console.